# Expandable List view value selection in android

Tags: android, android-adapter, android-adapterview

I set the many values in list and list view item contains the button and name. while select the item in the list to change the color, if i scroll the list item the selection is removed.

**Below code**

```
 @Override
    public View getGroupView(final int i, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
       final GroupViewHolder groupViewHolder;
        if(view==null) {
            groupViewHolder=new GroupViewHolder();
            view=((LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.product_listview_group_item,null);
            groupViewHolder.name=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.category_listview_item_name);
            groupViewHolder.price = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.category_listview_item_price);
            groupViewHolder.nameIcon=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.category_listview_item_icon);
            groupViewHolder.onClick=(ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.category_listview_item_onclick);
            view.setTag(groupViewHolder);
        } else {
            groupViewHolder=(GroupViewHolder)view.getTag();
        }
        groupViewHolder.nameIcon.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (groupViewHolder.nameIcon.getTag() == null) {                  groupViewHolder.name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffc400"));                   groupViewHolder.price.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffc400"));                    groupViewHolder.nameIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.yellow_circle_list_item);                    groupViewHolder.nameIcon.setTag(R.mipmap.yellow_circle_list_item);
                    dataHandler.addTempproducts(datas.get(i));
                } else {                    groupViewHolder.nameIcon.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.black_circle_list_item);                 groupViewHolder.name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));                  groupViewHolder.price.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
                    groupViewHolder.nameIcon.setTag(null);
                    dataHandler.removeTempProducts(datas.get(i));
                }
            }
        });
        if(datas.get(i).getPrice().isEmpty()) {
            groupViewHolder.price.setText(datas.get(i).getPrice());
        } else  {
            groupViewHolder.price.setText(datas.get(i).getPrice() + "/-");
        }
        groupViewHolder.name.setText(datas.get(i).getName());
        return view;
    }
```